# Cannot remove last part of a list

Tags: python, string, list, file-handling

I'm trying to write a program. This program reads a string obtained from a file, separates them, and removes any '{' and replaces it with a colon (which I am attempting to do right now). If there's a '}' on a line by itself, the line is removed entirely. Then it puts the new line into another file.

i.e. if I had: "Def StackExchange{"
the program should return "Def StackExchange:"

I am trying to tackle this by splitting the string by the whitespace, and putting it into a list. Afterwards I loop through the string and remove any '{' and append the list with a ":".

The issue is that when I try to remove a '{' or add an ':', I get a ValueError, stating that '{' isn't in the list despite the character being on the list.

this is what I have so far:

```
        readfile = open(filename + ".bpy","r")
writefile = open(filename + ".py","w")

line = readfile.readline()
string2 = []
while line != "":
    string = line
    string2 = []
    string2.append(string.split())
    if "{" in string2:
        for x in string2:
            try:
                string2.remove("{")
                string2.append(":")
                string = string2.join(" ")
            except:
                pass

    writefile.write(string)
    string2 = []  #This resets string2 and makes it empty so that loop goes on
    line = readfile.readline()


writefile.close()
readfile.close()
```

edit: Without using .replace

Comment: why don't you use `.replace("{",":")` ?

Comment: You are removing elements from the same list you are looping, that is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use splitting lines in word lists for this task at all. My suggestion:

```
with open(filename + '.bpy') as readfile, \
        open(filename + '.py', 'w') as writefile:
    for line in readfile:
        if '{' in line:
            line = line.replace('{', ':')
        elif '}' in line:
            continue

        writefile.write(line)
```

Using @Aswin suggestion, you could replace curly brackets straight in that loop:

```
string2 = []
for character in string:
     if character == '{':
          string2.append(':')
     else:
          string2.append(character)
string = ''.join(string2)
```

Comment: Yes, Sorry about that, I made a mistake in the edit. Normally I WOULD use .replace() but I'm trying to do this without using .replace()

Comment: Anyway, you can not change a list using for or while loops. In addition, if you remove an element from the list, it is removed at the particular index. If you append a new element to the list, it is added at the end of that list and not inserted at the index you would expect. However, in your case this would work as you expect because all those '{' are likely to be at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with split method implemented to convert string into separate words. It won't separate '{', if it doesn't have a space between the other characters and '{'.
It's better to separate each character and process it, like the following snippet.

```
string2 = list(string)
```

It will do the wonder.
else,

```
string2 = []
for character in string:
     string2.append(character)
```

It will rip each character and store it in array. Now your condition will work.

Comment: Alright, thanks I'll try doing it character by character, not word by word